# MySQL select DATETIME BETWEEN

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am trying to write a query that returns only the rows which has Datetime to be  **between** the **day 01 of the month and current day**. But I am not sure if it is possible to do. So, I am aware of the function `NOW()` that gives me the *current DATETIME*  but I still don't know how to get the other end of `BETWEEN` automatically since its a web application and i don't want to make the user input the datetime.

Ex: I want all the orders that were made during the month where you are consulting.

```
Select * from orders where date between (the function I am looking for) and NOW();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table_name 
where (date between  DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), interval 30 day), interval 1 day) AND CURDATE() )
```

or 
Your kinda approach..

```
select * from table_name 
where (date between  DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') AND NOW() )
```

or you can also do this

```
select * from table_name 
where `date` between curdate() - dayofmonth(curdate()) + 1
                 and curdate()
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses index better (if any)

```
DECLARE @iniDate DATE
DECLARE @endDate DATE

SET @endDate = curdate()
SET @iniDate = @endDate - dayofmonth(@endDate) + 1

SELECT *
FROM My_table
WHERE `My_date` BETWEEN @iniDate AND @endDate
```